# How many sets of non-adjacent edges in the 600-cell?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, symmetry, polytopes, big-numbers

(This is a simpler variant of my previous question, with one colour instead of two.)

The [*600-cell*](https://www.qfbox.info/4d/600-cell) is a 4D regular polytope. It has $120$ vertices, $720$ edges, $1200$ triangular faces, and $600$ tetrahedral cells. Each vertex touches $12$ edges, in an icosahedral arrangement.

Two edges are *adjacent* if they're part of one triangular face. The number of adjacent pairs of edges is $1200\times\binom{3}{2}=3600$.

**Question 1:** How many subsets (of that set of $720$ edges) have no adjacent pairs of edges?

**Question 2:** How many of these are distinct, considering symmetries of the 600-cell?

An obvious upper bound for these numbers is the total number of subsets, $2^{720}\approx5.515\times10^{216}$.

---

The [*rectified 600-cell*](https://www.qfbox.info/4d/rect600cell) is a 4D uniform polytope, whose vertices correspond to the edges of the 600-cell, with the same adjacency relations. It has $720$ vertices and $3600$ edges. Each vertex touches $10$ edges.

So I may equivalently ask about sets of non-adjacent vertices in the rectified 600-cell:

**Question 1:** How many vertex-induced subgraphs (of the rectified 600-cell's graph) have no edges?

**Question 2:** How many of these are distinct, considering symmetries of the rectified 600-cell?

---

An approximate answer would still be appreciated.

Let $A_1$ and $A_2$ be the answers to the two questions (respectively). The order of the 600-cell's symmetry group is $600\times24=14400$, where the $24$ is from tetrahedral symmetry. Thus, for each subset, there are between $1$ and $14400$ subsets in its orbit under the symmetry group. As $A_1$ counts the subsets and $A_2$ counts the orbits, we get

$$A_2\leq A_1\leq14400A_2.$$

In fact, it seems very likely that a random subset would have no symmetry; all $14400$ subsets in its orbit would be unequal to each other. So I'm expecting

$$A_1\approx14400A_2.$$

And I think $A_2$ would be more difficult to compute than $A_1$. Indeed, ignoring the adjacency condition, we'd have $2^{720}$ for $A_1$, but nothing so easy for $A_2$.

Comment: I think in question 1 the subsets are already the pairs of vertices that form edges. So you're overthinking these hypersets.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Edges are subsets of cardinality 2. Of those, there are only 720 in the 600-cell, and the question is, of those 720, how many are not part of a triangular face

Comment: Every edge is part of a triangular face, so your number would be $0$. But I'm talking about adjacent _pairs of edges_, not edges as _adjacent pairs of vertices_.

Comment: See the second section of the OP, if you want to talk about sets of vertices rather than sets of edges.

Comment: Since the 600-cell is regular, all edges are equivalent. Specifically, each edge is part of $5$ triangles and $5$ tetrahedra.

Answer (score 5):

This following images will help better understand the structure of the $600-$Cell when considered as a graph.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could I ask the program you use? Is this a freeware?

Comment: The program only exists on my local drive. I don't know how to upload it ? But I will happily make it publicly available ... If someone tells me how to.

Comment: One way to share: open a github account and post there. https://github.com/

Comment: Guideline on how to create a [git repo](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/create-a-repo)

Comment: If you consider it only as a graph, be careful with the definition of adjacent edges. It's not enough that they share a vertex; they must share a 3-cycle.

Comment: Could you explain the pictures in the post and how they contribute to answering the question?